# How to write Mongo db changeset to remove child node

Tags: java, mongodb, changeset

I have a List of Documents like below which I got it from Mongodb

```
{
"_id":"some_random_id"
"name": "report1"
"reportDef":
    {
    "reportParameters":
        ["a",
        "b",
        "c",
        "d",
        "e"
        ]
    }
    
"type": "CUSTOM"
"reportId": "desiredReport"
}


{
"_id":"some_random_id"
"name": "report1"
"reportDef":
    {
    "reportParameters":
        ["e",
        "f",
        "b",
        "y",
        "z"
        ]
    }
    
"type": "CUSTOM"
"reportId": "desiredReport"
}
```

and I need to remove "b" from the reportParameters if this condition satisfies i.e., if type="CUSTOM" and reportId="desiredReport"

means final json document should be like below

```
{
"_id":"some_random_id"
"name": "report1"
"reportDef":
    {
    "reportParameters":
        ["a",
        "c",
        "d",
        "e"
        ]
    }
    
"type": "CUSTOM"
"reportId": "desiredReport"
}

{
"_id":"some_random_id"
"name": "report1"
"reportDef":
    {
    "reportParameters":
        ["e",
        "f",
        "y",
        "z"
        ]
    }
    
"type": "CUSTOM"
"reportId": "desiredReport"
}
```

How to add changeset to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

```bash
db.collection.updateMany(
  {
    "type": "CUSTOM",
    "reportId": "desiredReport"
  },
  {
    "$pull": {
      "reportDef.reportParameters": "b"
    }
  }
);
```

Comment: Your answer only contains code. I recommend that you don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.